# Why can't I enter a decimal point in a bound UITextView?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I'm binding a `UITextView` to a field of data type `float`, and it seems that the binding mechanism is being over-vigilant in validating my data such that I cannot actually enter floating point numbers.

Specifically, if I type "7" in my UITextView, the float field in the data model updates.  If I paste "7.2" in the text view, it also updates.  But if I type "7." (on the way to typing "7.2"), the binding fails with error:

> MvxBind:Error:365.27 SetValue failed with exception - FormatException: Invalid format.

This is arguably correct, since "7." isn't a valid numeric string.

But it also discards the decimal point, and so I can't enter my number.  It just leaves "7" in the text view.  The weird thing is that this is ONLY affecting the decimal point/period character.  If I type "7X", it doesn't bind, but it does let me type the X. What's going on here?

Comment: This has been addressed recently - see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/350 - for double I believe there is a working example in apiexamples in mvvmcross-tutorials - see TextView in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/ApiExamples/ApiExamples.Touch/Views/FirstView.cs

Answer (score 0):

Just may be try to bind to string value and make a little manually in code string<=>float conversions? Also this should be much better way on monotouch specifically since based on the common .net functions rather than on the UI implementation.

Comment: I'm afraid I really don't understand what you're saying here.

Comment: I don't think you should bind UITextView to float field. You should bind it to the string field. And if you need this string to be translated to float you should check the format by yourself in code-behind.